# What is the way to store image files and audio files in a Windows Modern(Metro) UI apps?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have around 30 image files and 30 audio files in my Windows 8 Modern(Metro) UI app.Currently my application size is around 30MB.I want to reduce the size of my app.

So is there a way to repesent image files and aduio files in the format of the text/strings using any WinJS API ,so that it reduces size of the application.

Answer (score 0):

If your images or audio are uncompressed for some reason, you could certainly use a compressed format (jpeg or mp3 for example).  But, one methodology you might follow to reduce the size of your appx would be to only include images and audio that you immediately need and download the rest from a web service when the app first runs or when the files are actually needed.  There is a [Compressor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.compression.compressor.aspx) in WinRT, but it will not give you any real compression benefit over an already compressed image type like jpeg or audio type like mp3.

Comment: For this scenario be careful to warn users that your downloading a lot of data over a metered network.

Comment: I would advice against this. Windows 8 devices/tablets are not necessarily always online. It makes sense to download everything an app needs at install time and then offer a fast and uncompromised app experience.

Answer (score 0):

30MB is an acceptable size for a Windows 8 App. Why are you concerned about the size?

Storing your images as zipped resources won't help because .appx packages are already compressed so all you would do is CPU overhead at runtime because you need to uncompress unnecessarily.

I wouldn't worry about it too much. 30MB is okay but of course you should always strive to keep your size to a minimum. One sure way to reduce size is to be smart on how you store your images and audio files.

**For audio files**

- Check that you don't have uncompressed files (.wav).
- Check that your .mp3 files or similar use an appropriate bitrate. You probably only need 128kbps

**For image files**

- Check that your image files use an appropriate compression method. Some files might be okay to store as JPEG, others are best stored as GIF while still others might be best to be stored as PNG.
- Optimize your PNG files with tools like [PNG Gauntlet](http://pnggauntlet.com/). These tools bring down file sizes substantially **without reducing quality** of the PNG files.

**Windows 8 Scaling support**

Also, make sure that your images properly support windows 8 image scaling. More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx).